# Buddy SFTP deployment - deploy from specific commit

Tags: git, deployment, sftp

After signing up at https://Buddy.works I have setup a pipeline for SFTP deployment - but it wants on initial deploy to upload ALL files.

Subsequent deployments would only be the new files.

AS this is a large project I dont want to reupload all files... how can one start uploading files from a specific git commit?

Answer (score 1):

Buddy.works support answered my question - they already support this feature:

> In the pipeline settings, you can set "current revision". With this set, whenever you run an execution it will only upload the difference between the "current revision" and the revision selected for deployment.

Answer (score 0):

A specific Git commit would reference *all* files of a repository, since this is what a commit is (a pointer to a snapshot of the full repository).

A commit *diff* (with, for instance, the parent commit) might reference fewer files, so you [might clone a repo without checking it out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59276976/6309), and then checkout/**[restore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066072/6309)** only the files you want, [as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35362641/6309)

```
 cd /path/to/local/cloned/repo
 git diff --diff-filter=AM --name-only <aSHA> <aSHA>~1 | xargs git restore
```

From that partially checked out repository, you could initiate your sftp.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I am however looking for a more Buddy.works way of making this work. I could not add a new tag for "buddy.works" as this is application specific.